# MYSQL - Help joining to just 1 row

Tags: mysql

I'm currently getting more than one row returned and so I'm trying to join on the most recent item using this join.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts wp_posts1 ON (wp_posts.ID = (SELECT MAX(post_parent) FROM wp_posts1 WHERE wp_posts1.post_parent = wp_posts.ID) )
```

but I get the error 'SQL Error: Table 'web13-a-tablename.wp_posts1' doesn't exist'.

My original code below which returns too many results.

```
SELECT 
wp_posts.ID, 
wp_posts.post_title, 
wp_posts1.guid AS f_image,
wp_posts1.id AS f_ID 
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts wp_posts1 ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_posts1.post_parent) AND wp_posts1.post_type = 'attachment'  
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'custom' 
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%smith%' OR wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%jones%')
ORDER BY 
f_ID DESC
```

SQLFiddle showing multiple rows selected. I want to just get one row and I want to select the largest f_ID. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97ee9/3/0

Result required:

```
ID       POST_TITLE       F_IMAGE       F_ID
--------------------------------------------
2365     John Jones       IMG_URL       2490
2385     Becky Smith      IMG_URL       2390
```

Comment: My sense is that there's more to this problem than meets the eye. Consider providing a sqlfiddle, including the desired result set.

Comment: Added a SQLFiddle as you suggested.

Comment: For clarity, can you please provide the desired result.

Comment: Added the required results as suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the subquery to:

```
SELECT MAX(post_parent) FROM wp_posts as w3 WHERE w3.post_parent = wp_posts.ID
```

**UPDATE** changed the query in the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f1456/2) to:

```
SELECT 
  wp_posts.ID, 
  wp_posts.post_title, 
  wp_posts1.guid AS f_image,
  MAX(wp_posts1.id) AS f_ID 
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts wp_posts1 ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_posts1.post_parent) AND wp_posts1.post_type = 'attachment'  
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'custom' 
  AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
  AND (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%smith%')
GROUP BY
  wp_posts.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work for me. I've added a SQLFiddle to the question now.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I should have included more data in the Fiddle. What you've posted works but I'm pulling multiple records so ORDER and LIMIT 1 doesn't work. I've updated the fiddle again. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97ee9/3/0

Comment: @PaulBenbow in your fiddle you DON'T have `LIMIT 1` after `ORDER BY` so that is why multiple rows are returned

Comment: I want multiple rows returned, just not duplicate rows for the same user. LIMIT 1 will give me just 1.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to SQLFiddle and we seem to be looking at two slightly different queries and my original question wasn't detailed enough. Pls see the updated question and the SQLFiddle there http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97ee9/3/0 I tried GROUP BY there but it didn't return the MAX F_ID. I think it needs something like LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts AS wp_posts1 ON (wp_posts.ID = (SELECT MAX(wp_posts1.post_parent) FROM wp_posts1 WHERE wp_posts1.post_parent = wp_posts.ID) ) but I can't get it working.

Comment: No it's not. The results I require are in the question above. I should have just 2 rows, 1 for Jones and 1 for Smith. The F_ID in each row should be the MAX value of those returned.

Comment: got it now... you need `MAX` function, pls see the updated query

Comment: That's it! Thank you, much appreciated. I've updated the SQLFiddle with your amended query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97ee9/5